# Are there side effects to using string concatenation or jQuery inside jquery selectors?

Tags: jquery

while exploring jQuery I came up with the following weird script. I don't see myself doing this really however concatenating strings to achieve a variable name is not unusual in JavaScript.

Any feedback welcome.

```
...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var a = 'y';
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('p[id^=' + $('p[id=x]').html() + a + "]").css('color','blue');
        });
    </script>
...

<p id="x">2a</p>
<p id="2ay_">mytext</p>
```

Comment: Naw, please comment your code though. It's easy to write JS that's cryptic.

Comment: be careful with DOM ids that start with a number!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no, there aren't side-effects.  Your example is quirky, but as you said you were just exploring to see what you could do.  I have used string concatenation and function value returns inside jQuery selectors before, it can be a useful technique for managing sets of related elements which reside in different parts of the DOM.

I admit I haven't used `jQuery.html()` inside a selector, but there isn't any inherent reason why that's "bad".  I just can't think of a situation where that'd be strictly necessary.  It does make the code rather... unusual, and hence more difficult to understand and maintain.

If you actually find a use for this in production code, please let us know.  I'd be fascinated to see what it is. :)

Comment: Just wondering about some black magic in jQuery that would give unwanted side effects inside selectors. What I find myself needing is a to pass the 'search' string to the selector at runtime. Could by the way, jQuery do with this pattern:
$('p[id=?]').click(paramValue, function() {}); ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion its unreadable, unmaintainable...anything like that should be avoided. Imagine you joined a new company and they put you in front of a whole bunch of js/jquery code that looked like that!!

P.S you should use addClass to change the color. I would rather change a css class after all it is a style setting and is also more extensible in that you can add other styles without any more js code.

Answer (score 0):

No, nothing weird. Other than maybe some unwanted results if someone/you went and modified the HTML within the p element. It is definitely pretty weird the way it's coded, but nothing really wrong with it (other than being unreadable/unmaintainable).

Because jQuery is nothing special -- it's just a Javascript library. You aren't using some special JS syntax or anything, jQuery is simply taking a string and using it as a selector. So that string can be constructed any way you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering about some black magic in jQuery that would give unwanted side effects inside selectors. What I find myself needing is a to pass the 'search' string to the selector at runtime.

Could by the way, jQuery do with this pattern:

$('p[id=?]').click(paramValue, function() {}); where the paramValue replaces the placeholder '?' ?

Answer (score 0):

Yep no reason you can't do this. Since `$` is actually a function call itself anything that needs to be evaluated in order to pass a parameter to it is evaluated first.